# Do I need to explain myself about choosing an Apple-based product?

Tags: discussion

As a proud Apple fan, I would like to use Apple product even on the server side. I was asking a [question about clustering Apple Mac Mini servers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148198/pro-and-cons-of-using-clusters-of-mac-mini-servers), and one user asked: "Why do  you want to use Apple Mini Server?". Just as a rule of thumb for my future questions, do I need to explain myself on why I would like to use Apple-based products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are (among other things) intended for asking follow-up and clarification questions to a post, in your case the question you've asked. I understand the comment primarily as an inquiry about any functional needs to run OS X on your server (e.g. you are developing a server component with Objective C or are you planning to deploy this into an all-Apple environment). Clarifactions like this can help to improve the question and its constraints, which usually results in better answers.